# Allow only in-cluster ingress for calico network policy

Tags: kubernetes, network-interface, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I want to create a `globalnetworkpolicy` for an interface. I am using Calico `HostendPoint` for the interface and defining `globalnetworkpolicy` for the `hostendpoint`. I would like to create a `globalnetworkpolicy` that allows only ingress from within the cluster. A sample is given [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/tutorials/protect-hosts).

In-cluster traffic is the traffic from pods and from nodes.
I have the `podCIDR`, so I can use that to ensure that traffic from pods are allowed.
How do I allow traffic from nodes' own `IPAddresses` as per the link above?
What is the nodes' own `IPaddresses` mentioned in the link?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically referring to Kubernetes node - more precisely to [node resource](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/resources/node), which is created when a  `calico/node`  instance is started.  Calico automatically detects each node’s IP address and subnet,  and alongside with AS association and tunnel address (IP-in-IP or VXLAN),  they are listed in [node resource configuration](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/networking/node#understanding-caliconode-ip-autodetection-logic).

Comment: Thank you. So that means to ensure in-cluster-traffic, i have to whitelist the pod cidr and node ip+subnet. Does that mean another node in the same subnet can still access the internal resources

Comment: @ParvathyMohan Yes, it shouldn't affect node in the same subnet.